# how to deal with one class problem in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am building some parts for manufacturing and i receive time series data of current and voltage from each part. I want to benchmark a part as good one.

I want to use the data from a part that is perfectly good and tells the model this data is normal in training.

then i want the model to differentiate normal and outliers in my test data(other parts).

In this way, i want to detect defects in the part by comparing it to the normal data.

I have tried one class SVM (novelty detection) for this but i am not getting fruitful results.

Can you suggest me any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection). In your case it is supervised anomaly detection. This is a good [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-machine-learning-for-anomaly-detection-and-condition-monitoring-6742f82900d7).

There are variety of ways/algorithms that detects anomalies. Depending on your type of data you can try:

The Mahalanobis distance 
Isolation Forest 
DBSCAN 
Support Vector Machines 
Local Outlier Factor 
Autoencoders 
...

Comment: Anomaly detection is using whole data of one part and tells which are anomalies in that data(part). I want to compare the data with a data having no anomalies(good data) and then model tells me that these are anomalies, because it could be that whole part is bad but anomaly detection will consider it as normal as it has more density

Comment: Exactly. You can use your model to just learn **only** the good data points and totally ignore the bad data points. If you have enough good data points to fit a model the ratio between good and bad points no longer matter. In other words you have learnt a multi-modal distribution of good points only. Now you can use this model to find out which points are close/in in the learnt distribution and which are far away and by how far(`d`). Based on observations you can set a threshold distance (`t`). e.g., if `d <= t` then classify as good else bad.

Comment: one more question, should i use raw data i am getting from sensors(after cleaning) or should i also create statistical features (mean,peak value ) etc and use them in the model too

Comment: I am not sure about you use case. But IMO, you should **not** because these are aggregated properties and will not be available when you test them on a single data point. Meaning you testing data should be similar to your train case in order to make sensible predictions.